# Get first array objects in every second arrays index

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Get first array objects in every second arrays index . Is it possible to get like this given expected output or not possible, we can use for or any other method in JavaScript This is the Two arrays:

```
let First = [
  {lesson: 1},
  {lesson: 2},
  {lesson: 3}
]
# let Second = [
  {
    name: "John",
    age : 26,
    lesson: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Ken",
    age : 40,
    lesson: 2
  },
  {
    name: "William",
    age : 18,
    lesson: 3
  }
]
```

Expected output

```
  {
    name: "John",
    age : 26,
    lesson: 1,
    lesson: 2,
    lesson: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Ken",
    age : 40,
    lesson: 1,
    lesson: 2,
    lesson: 3
  },
  {
    name: "William",
    age : 18,
    lesson: 1,
    lesson: 2,
    lesson: 3
  },
]
```

Comment: Hi @Jegan, try to add your code, even if it is a small snippet, do not use the community as a problem solver. That is why you are receiving negative votes.

Comment: you can not have more same named properties. take an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can't have multiple key with différent value in a object but you can do that if you want :

```js
 const persons = [{
    name: "John",
    age : 26,
    lesson: [1, 2, 3],
  },
  {
    name: "Ken",
    age : 40,
    lesson: [1, 2, 3],
  },
  {
    name: "William",
    age : 18,
    lesson: [1, 2, 3],
  },
]
```

And with code :

```js
for (let i = 0; i < second.length; i++) {
  second[i]["lesson"] = [1, 2, 3]
}
```